# Crash when trying to open Filtered Questions

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, 500-server-error

I get error page when trying to open https://stackexchange.com/filters

It says

```
Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
```

But it was not fixed for couple weeks. I think it's due to removing a login that was associated with my stack account. Probably non-consistent DB state.

Could you please fix my account.

Comment: Does this still happen for you?

Comment: Hi rene,
Yes, still the same error.